# Is the tire safe still?

Tags: tires

Bare with me I am NOT mechanically inclined .

I hit some ice and slid into a curb. It's currently -37°C where I live. 
Anyways no air coming out but when I was driving 70-80km I could smell rubber burning so I pulled over check it out seemed OK and continued home driving slower (30-40km) & the smell went away.

The tire will get replaced but I need to pick up kids from school today is it safe to do.so or should I just arrange something else. [image][image]

Answer (score 4):

The damage is on the most vulnerable part of the tire. It really is not safe to drive it in that condition, especially at high speeds. It is apt to have a blow out and if your travelling with kids  and also considering others on the road, I would get it fixed ASAP. As far as the burning smell, there could of been some damage or bent to suspension parts which also is a safety factor. This vehicle should be looked at by a reputable repair shop.